# CSS: Full width of drop down men

Tags: css

I found below menu online and I like it, I want to change its width to 1400px. I tried to edit its CSS to match my header width for but I couldn't succeed.

**Before I edit it**

[image]

**After I edit it**

[image]

**CSS Code**

```
.nav,
.nav a,
.nav ul,
.nav li,
.nav div,
.nav form,
.nav input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width:100%; // What I have changed only
}

.nav a { text-decoration: none; }

.nav li { list-style: none; }

/* Menu Container */
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 500;
}

/* Menu List */
.nav > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

/* Menu Links */
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 510;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 54px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);

    background: #771203;
    border-left: 1px solid #4b4441;
    border-right: 1px solid #312a27;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.nav > li:hover > a { background: #4b4441; }

.nav > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-left: none;
}

/* Search Form */
.nav > li.nav-search > form {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    height: 54px;
    z-index: 510;
    border-left: 1px solid #4b4441;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    line-height: 24px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999999;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);

    background: #771203;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    transition: all .3s ease 1s;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus { color: #fcfcfc; }

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus,
.nav > li.nav-search:hover input[type="text"] {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 15px 20px;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    transition: all .3s ease .1s;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;

    background: #771203 url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat center center;

    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"]:hover { background-color: #4b4441; }

/* Menu Dropdown */
.nav > li > div {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;

    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}

.nav > li:hover > div {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Menu Content Styles */
.nav .nav-column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.nav .nav-column h3 {
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
    line-height: 18px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #771203;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav .nav-column h3.orange { color: #ff722b; }

.nav .nav-column li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #888888;
}

.nav .nav-column li a:hover { color: #666666; }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/wz9nbto9/)**

**My Probem**

I want the menu items to be in an inline order(next to each other) just like the original menu but with 1400px or 100% width and menu the items are in the middle.

Comment: Can you please provide your html, and identify what you changed.

Comment: provide a working example js fiddle, that way we can help you easier

Comment: @haxxxton I added my html, the only thing I have changed was adding width:100%; for all the classes at the first block of the css script

Comment: @VictorRadu check the Fiddle demo please

Comment: @Learner, given the search box "expands" on hover, how did you envision this working with a 100% wide nav bar? is it only 100% when the search bar is expanded? or is the search bar always visible?

Comment: @haxxxton You are right, I will make the box in fixed width, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` for this purpose. Check the solution below, and here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tayn69Lj/)

```css
.nav,
.nav a,
.nav ul,
.nav li,
.nav div,
.nav form,
.nav input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.nav a { text-decoration: none; }

.nav li { list-style: none; width:100%; }

/* Menu Container */
.nav {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 500;
}

/* Menu List */
.nav > li {
    float: left;
}

/* Menu Links */
.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 510;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 54px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);

    background: #771203;
    border-left: 1px solid #4b4441;
    border-right: 1px solid #312a27;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.nav > li:hover > a { background: #4b4441; }

.nav > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-left: none;
}

/* Search Form */
.nav > li.nav-search > form {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    height: 54px;
    z-index: 510;
    border-left: 1px solid #4b4441;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    line-height: 24px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999999;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);

    background: #771203;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
    transition: all .3s ease 1s;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus { color: #fcfcfc; }

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus,
.nav > li.nav-search:hover input[type="text"] {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 15px 20px;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
    transition: all .3s ease .1s;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;

    background: #771203 url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat center center;

    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"]:hover { background-color: #4b4441; }

/* Menu Dropdown */
.nav > li > div {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;

    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}

.nav > li:hover > div {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Menu Content Styles */
.nav .nav-column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.nav .nav-column h3 {
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
    line-height: 18px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #771203;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav .nav-column h3.orange { color: #ff722b; }

.nav .nav-column li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #888888;
}

.nav .nav-column li a:hover { color: #666666; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"><img id="all" src="img/qa.png" alt="xxx"/></div>
  <div id="menu-wrapper">

    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <div>
                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pampers Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Huggies Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Seventh Generation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Derbies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pampers Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Huggies Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Seventh Generation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Derbies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3 class="orange">Related Categories</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pampers Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Huggies Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diapers</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3 class="orange">Brands</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MOE</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">EEC-SEAA</a>
            <div>
                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3 class="orange">Related Categories</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pampers Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Huggies Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diapers</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3 class="orange">Brands</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pampers Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Huggies Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Seventh Generation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Derbies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-column">
                    <h3>Home</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pampers Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Huggies Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Seventh Generation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diapers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Derbies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Driving shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Espadrilles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Achievements</a></li>
        <li class="nav-search">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much your help, I never used display:flex before